# PHP Warning: Undefined array key "VirtualHostSubMenu" in index.php

Tags: php, errors

I'm creating a new WordPress site but I'm hitting a WSoD when trying to access wp-admin. The only error present in all of the logs is PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "VirtualHostSubMenu" in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 52 and is present in the PHP logs. I have checked the httpd syntax and all the present logs. I haven't modified the index.php file at all. It is exactly as I recieved it in the WordPress.zip I received when I downloaded it this morning.

What should I do?